# How to randomly choose any 4 key-value pairs from the singleton class in kotlin to display them in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have created a singleton class where I have written 'n' number of key-value pairs, in which the values are Pair like below. My issue is, when I initially open this fragment, it displays 4 different key-value like below [When I open my fragment first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJoW0.jpg)

When I click the shuffle button again, it doesn't display random image and words but it only change the positions of images and the words that were shown first time when I had opened the fragment. It shows like this [On clicking the button it shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoKkZ.jpg)

And then when I click again, the positions of image and names change again but the names and images don't get displayed from random pairs of singleton class but the original 4 pairs that were displayed when I had opened the Fragment like this [On clicking the button 2nd time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1L6m.jpg)

Below is the code

1. The object class

```kotlin
object ImageStore {
    
        val imagesNamesMap = hashMapOf(
            R.drawable.africa to Pair("Africa","Afrika"),
            R.drawable.asia to Pair("Asia","Azija"),
            R.drawable.europe to Pair("Europe","Europa"),
            R.drawable.antartica to Pair("Antarctica","Antarktida"),
            R.drawable.airplane to Pair("Aeroplane","Lėktuvas"),
            R.drawable.apple1 to Pair("Apple","Obuolys"),
            R.drawable.key to Pair("Key","raktas"),
            R.drawable.sleep to Pair("to sleep","miegoti"),
            R.drawable.shopping to Pair("to shop","apsipirkti"),
            R.drawable.cinemascreen to Pair("to watch a movie","Žiūrėti filmą"),
            R.drawable.goshopping to Pair("I go shopping","aš einu apsipirkti"),
            R.drawable.what1 to Pair("What is it?","Kas tai?"),
            R.drawable.japanesefood to Pair("Japanese food","Japonų maistas"),
            R.drawable.hotcoffee to Pair("hot coffee","karšta kava"),
            R.drawable.eat to Pair("to eat","valgyti"),
            R.drawable.ofcourse to Pair("Of course","Žinoma"),
            R.drawable.rice to Pair("rice","ryžiai"),
            R.drawable.soup1 to Pair("soup","sriuba"),
            R.drawable.bread1 to Pair("Bread","Duona"),
            R.drawable.water1 to Pair("water","vanduo"),
            R.drawable.glass1 to Pair("a glass","stiklinė"),
            R.drawable.apple1 to Pair("apple","obuolys"),
            R.drawable.cost to Pair("to cost","kainuoti"),
            R.drawable.parents1 to Pair("parents","tėvai"),
            R.drawable.classmate to Pair("classmate","klasiokas"),
            R.drawable.friends1 to Pair("my friends","Mano draugai"),
            R.drawable.little to Pair("a little","šiek tiek"),
            R.drawable.go to Pair("Let's go","eikime!"),
            R.drawable.more to Pair("more","daugiau"),
            R.drawable.hand to Pair("hand","ranka"),
            R.drawable.stopsign to Pair("to stop","nustoti"),
            R.drawable.march to Pair("March","Kovas"),
            R.drawable.february to Pair("February","Vasaris"),
            R.drawable.january to Pair("January","Sausis"),
            R.drawable.saturday to Pair("Saturday","Šeštadienis"),
            R.drawable.friday to Pair("Friday","penktadienis"),
            R.drawable.thursday to Pair("Thursday","Ketvirtadienis"),
            R.drawable.wednesday to Pair("Wednesday","Trečiadienis"),
            R.drawable.tuesday to Pair("Tuesday","Antradienis"),
            R.drawable.monday to Pair("Monday","Pirmadienis"),
            R.drawable.sunday to Pair("Sunday","Sekmadienis"),
            R.drawable.autumn to Pair("autumn","ruduo"),
            R.drawable.summer to Pair("Summer","vasara"),
            R.drawable.spring to Pair("Spring","pavasaris"),
            R.drawable.december to Pair("December","Gruodis"),
            R.drawable.november to Pair("November","lapkritis"),
            R.drawable.october to Pair("October","Spalis"),
            R.drawable.september to Pair("September","Rugsėjis"),
            R.drawable.august to Pair("August","Rugpjūtis"),
            R.drawable.july to Pair("July","Liepa"),
            R.drawable.june to Pair("June","Birželis"),
            R.drawable.may to Pair("May","Gegužė"),
            R.drawable.april to Pair("April","Balandis"),
            R.drawable.march to Pair("March","Kovas"),
            R.drawable.noon to Pair("Noon","vidurdienis"),
            R.drawable.morning to Pair("Morning","rytas"),
            R.drawable.evening to Pair("evening","vakaras"),
            R.drawable.beforesleep to Pair("before sleep","prieš miegą"),
            R.drawable.halfaday to Pair("half a day","pusę dienos"),
            R.drawable.midnight to Pair("Midnight","vidurnaktis"),
            R.drawable.decade to Pair("decade","dešimtmetį"),
            R.drawable.season to Pair("Season","sezonas"),
            R.drawable.year to Pair("Year","metai"),
            R.drawable.month to Pair("Month","Mėnuo"),
            R.drawable.day to Pair("day","diena"),
            R.drawable.winter to Pair("winter","žiema"),
            R.drawable.key to Pair("period","laikotarpį"),
            R.drawable.workday to Pair("workday","darbo diena"),
            R.drawable.weekend to Pair("weekend","savaitgalis"),
            R.drawable.twice to Pair("twice","du kartus"),
            R.drawable.once to Pair("once","vieną kartą"),
            R.drawable.week to Pair("week","savaitė"),
            R.drawable.tomorrow to Pair("tomorrow","rytoj"),
            R.drawable.today to Pair("Today","šiandien"),
            R.drawable.inafternoon to Pair("in the afternoon","po pietų"),
            R.drawable.early to Pair("early","anksti"),
            R.drawable.late to Pair("late","vėlai"),
    
        ).toList().shuffled().take(4).toMap()
    }
```

I want any 4 elements to be displayed randomly everytime I click on the button, the button is in the Fragment PractiseFragment.kt like shown below

```kotlin
class PractiseFragment : Fragment() {
            lateinit var binding: FragmentPractiseBinding
            lateinit var practiseAdapter: PractiseAdapter
            lateinit var  recyclerViewPractise: RecyclerView
        
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            override fun onCreateView(
                inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                savedInstanceState: Bundle?
            ): View {
                // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        
                binding = FragmentPractiseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater,container,false)
                recyclerViewPractise = binding.recyclerViewPractise
        
        
                val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
                binding.recyclerViewPractise.layoutManager = layoutManager
        
        
                // Shuffle the list of image names
               //val shuffledImageNames = ImageStore.imagesNamesMap.values.toList().shuffleList()
                val shuffledImageResources = ImageStore.imagesNamesMap.keys.toList().shuffleList()
        
                val shuffledImageNames1: List<Pair<String, String>> = shuffledImageResources.mapNotNull { it ->
                    val pair = ImageStore.imagesNamesMap[it]
                    pair?.let { Pair(pair.first,pair.second)}
                }.toList().shuffleList()
        
        
                practiseAdapter = PractiseAdapter(shuffledImageResources.toMutableList(),
                    shuffledImageNames1.toMutableList(),binding.btnShuffle,recyclerViewPractise)
        
                binding.recyclerViewPractise.adapter = practiseAdapter
                practiseAdapter.initsetRecyclerView(recyclerViewPractise)
        
                return binding.root
        
            }
        
        }
```

Below is the layout file of the PractiseFragment

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_color"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                android:text="@string/select_correct_pair" />
    
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageCat"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cat1" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/zero1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearRecyclerview"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- RecyclerView to display the image cards -->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewPractise"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_practise_cards"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/shuffle"
            android:id="@+id/btnShuffle"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:background="@drawable/orangeractangle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearRecyclerview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the code for item_practise_cards.xml file

```xml
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="1">
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardImagePractise"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewPractise"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardTextPractise"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
    
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewPractise"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Random Name"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewPractise1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Random Name"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
    
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </GridLayout>
```

Below is the code of my Adapter class PractiseAdapter.kt

```kotlin
class PractiseAdapter(
        private var imageResources: MutableList<Int>,
        private var imageNames1: MutableList<Pair<String,String>>,
        btnShuffle: AppCompatButton,
        recyclerViewPractise: RecyclerView,
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PractiseAdapter.PractiseViewHolder>() {
    
        lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
        private var anyCardIsGreen = false
        private var selectedImageResource = -1
        private var selectedImageName = ""
        private var previousSelectedImageResource = -1
        private var previousSelectedImageName = ""
    
        init {
            btnShuffle.setOnClickListener {
                shuffleCards()
            }
        }
    
        private fun shuffleCards() {
            // Shuffle the card data (images and names)
            imageResources.shuffle()
            imageNames1.shuffle()
    
            // Reset the selected image and name
            selectedImageResource = -1
            selectedImageName = ""
            previousSelectedImageResource = -1
            previousSelectedImageName = ""
    
            // Reset the background color of cardImage views to white
            resetCardImageBackgroundToWhite()
    
    
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    
        fun initsetRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
            this.recyclerView = recyclerView
        }
    
        private fun resetCardImageBackgroundToWhite() {
            // Iterate through the card views and reset the background color of cardImage to white
            for (position in 0 until imageResources.size) {
    
                val holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position) as? PractiseViewHolder
                holder?.cardImagePractise?.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            }
        }
    
        companion object {
            val GREEN_COLOR = Color.parseColor("#ABEBC6")
        }
    
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PractiseViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_practise_cards, parent, false)
    
            return PractiseViewHolder(view)
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int = imageResources.size
    
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PractiseViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val imageResource = imageResources[position]
            val imageName1 = imageNames1[position]
    
    
            holder.imageViewPractise.setImageResource(imageResource)
            holder.textViewPractise.text = imageName1.first
            holder.textViewPractise1.text = imageName1.second
    
            holder.cardImagePractise.setOnClickListener {
                selectedImageResource = imageResource
                previousSelectedImageResource = selectedImageResource
                selectedImageName = ""
                notifyDataSetChanged()
                holder.cardImagePractise.setCardBackgroundColor(GREEN_COLOR)
            }
            holder.cardTextPractise.setOnClickListener {
                if (selectedImageResource == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        it.context,
                        "Please select an image card first.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                } else {
                    selectedImageName = imageNames1[position].first
                    previousSelectedImageName = selectedImageName
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            val nameColor = if(imageNames1[position].first ==selectedImageName){
                if(ImageStore.imagesNamesMap[selectedImageResource]?.first==selectedImageName){
                    Toast.makeText(
                        holder.itemView.context,
                        "Correct name selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    anyCardIsGreen=true
                    holder.cardTextPractise.setBackgroundColor(GREEN_COLOR) // Set green background for the name card
                    Color.GREEN
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        holder.itemView.context,
                        "Wrong name selected!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    Color.RED
                }
            } else {
                  holder.cardTextPractise.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
                  Color.WHITE
            }
            holder.cardTextPractise.setBackgroundColor(nameColor)
    
            // Check if the card is green and set anyCardIsGreen accordingly
    
        }

        class PractiseViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val cardImagePractise: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardImagePractise)
            val cardTextPractise: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardTextPractise)
            val imageViewPractise: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPractise)
            val textViewPractise: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPractise)
            val textViewPractise1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPractise1)
    
        }
    }
```

In short, I want to display random key-value pairs from the object class everytime I click on button and not just display the same original 4 pairs that were displayed when I had opened my Fragment for first time.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ImageStore` object to this

```kotlin
object ImageStore {
        private val _imagesNamesMap = hashMapOf(
            R.drawable.africa to Pair("Africa","Afrika"),
            R.drawable.asia to Pair("Asia","Azija"),
            // more data
        )

        val imagesNamesMap: Map<Int, String>
          get() = _imagesNamesMap.toList().shuffled().take(4).toMap() 
    }
```

Change `shuffleCards()` of `PractiseAdapter` to this

```kotlin
private fun shuffleCards() {
     imageResources = ImageStore.imagesNamesMap.keys.toList().shuffleList()
        
     imageNames1: List<Pair<String, String>> = shuffledImageResources.mapNotNull { it ->
                    val pair = ImageStore.imagesNamesMap[it]
                    pair?.let { Pair(pair.first,pair.second)}
                }.toList().shuffleList()


    // Reset the selected image and name
    selectedImageResource = -1
    selectedImageName = ""
    previousSelectedImageResource = -1
    previousSelectedImageName = ""

    // Reset the background color of cardImage views to white
    resetCardImageBackgroundToWhite()


    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: What changes shall I make in Fragment and Adapter class?

Comment: @kolmikaelson check updated answer

Comment: So , what will be the parameters of PractiseAdapter when it's called in the Fragment?

Comment: @kolmikaelson rest should stay as it is